# gradle clean cleanEclipse eclipse command is not able to build while installing mifos on windows

Tags: maven, gradle

I cloned the mifos repository in my pc. After that installed gradle 1.5
Folowed the instructions to install gradle from here https://github.com/openMF/mifosx/wiki/Gradle

wasnt able to figure out JAVA_OPTS and what it is..if somebody can help regarding that?
Then I went into the mifosng-provider directory and tried executing the following command which should work perfectly fine but it is not working and instead showed the following

```
c:\mifosx\mifosng-provider>gradle clean cleanEclipse eclipse
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8005

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.zeroturnaround:gradle-jrebel-plugin:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
      :mifosng-provider:unspecified
   > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/zerot
urnaround/gradle-jrebel-plugin/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
      > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/zeroturnaround/gradle-j
rebel-plugin/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
         > repo1.maven.org
   > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/c
ontent/groups/zt-public/org/zeroturnaround/gradle-jrebel-plugin/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/m
aven-metadata.xml.
      > Could not GET 'http://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/groups/zt-p
ublic/org/zeroturnaround/gradle-jrebel-plugin/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'
.
         > repos.zeroturnaround.com
   > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/zerot
urnaround/gradle-jrebel-plugin/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
      > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/zeroturnaround/gradle-j
rebel-plugin/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
         > repo1.maven.org
   > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/zerot
urnaround/gradle-jrebel-plugin/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
      > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/zeroturnaround/gradle-j
rebel-plugin/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
         > repo1.maven.org
   > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/zerot
urnaround/gradle-jrebel-plugin/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
      > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/zeroturnaround/gradle-j
rebel-plugin/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
         > repo1.maven.org
> Could not resolve org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9.7.
  Required by:
      :mifosng-provider:unspecified
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-
tomcat-plugin/0.9.7/gradle-tomcat-plugin-0.9.7.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/groups/zt-publ
ic/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-tomcat-plugin/0.9.7/gradle-tomcat-plugin-0.9.7.
pom'.
      > repos.zeroturnaround.com
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-
tomcat-plugin/0.9.7/gradle-tomcat-plugin-0.9.7.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-
tomcat-plugin/0.9.7/gradle-tomcat-plugin-0.9.7.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-
tomcat-plugin/0.9.7/gradle-tomcat-plugin-0.9.7.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
> Could not resolve nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.5.0.
  Required by:
      :mifosng-provider:unspecified
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/nl/javadude/gradle/plugins/lic
ense-gradle-plugin/0.5.0/license-gradle-plugin-0.5.0.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/groups/zt-publ
ic/nl/javadude/gradle/plugins/license-gradle-plugin/0.5.0/license-gradle-plugin-
0.5.0.pom'.
      > repos.zeroturnaround.com
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/nl/javadude/gradle/plugins/lic
ense-gradle-plugin/0.5.0/license-gradle-plugin-0.5.0.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/nl/javadude/gradle/plugins/lic
ense-gradle-plugin/0.5.0/license-gradle-plugin-0.5.0.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/nl/javadude/gradle/plugins/lic
ense-gradle-plugin/0.5.0/license-gradle-plugin-0.5.0.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
> Could not resolve com.github.ben-manes:gradle-flyway-plugin:0.2.
  Required by:
      :mifosng-provider:unspecified
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ben-manes/gradle-fl
yway-plugin/0.2/gradle-flyway-plugin-0.2.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/groups/zt-publ
ic/com/github/ben-manes/gradle-flyway-plugin/0.2/gradle-flyway-plugin-0.2.pom'.
      > repos.zeroturnaround.com
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ben-manes/gradle-fl
yway-plugin/0.2/gradle-flyway-plugin-0.2.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ben-manes/gradle-fl
yway-plugin/0.2/gradle-flyway-plugin-0.2.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ben-manes/gradle-fl
yway-plugin/0.2/gradle-flyway-plugin-0.2.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
> Could not resolve mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22.
  Required by:
      :mifosng-provider:unspecified
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1
.22/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/groups/zt-publ
ic/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.22/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.pom'.
      > repos.zeroturnaround.com
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1
.22/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1
.22/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1
.22/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 38.61 secs
```

Comment: I've tried to access the missing artifacts by using web browser. I can access them. Do you have any internet connection problem?

Comment: I dont have an internet connection problem but I use proxy and used git bash here and the proxy settings work fine since I successfully use git with the proxy

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I just had to set my proxy settings in gradle.properties file and it worked for me.